# Commerce Rules OR Condition

Tags: commerce, rules

I am trying to set up a simple OR condition.

If these "blocks" (red) are TRUE or these "blocks" (green) are TRUE execute the rule.

[image]

So I've tried added a OR block in various ways, but it does not succeed.

[image]

Basically what I want to achieve is that, if red block is NOT EMPTY or green block has value YES, the rule should execute.

Answer (score 0):

This thread helped me understand the logic.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1784196

Basically what tobiasb said:

> OR (All conditions below this or between the lines are OR-Conditions)
>   - condition1 (OR)
>   - AND  (All conditions below this or between the lines are AND-Conditions, default condition)
>   -- condition2 (AND)
>   -- condition3
>
> This means:
>
> condition1 OR (condition2 AND condition3)